# Font size control for pifont characters

Tags: fontsize, pifont

[image]

How can I enlarge the font size of pifont characters?
I tried to use `\large{\ding{204}}`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using these font elements via macros, you may just as well scale/resize them using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\scalebox`/`\resizebox`. Here's one option using the former:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,pifont}
\let\oldding\ding% Store old \ding in \oldding
\renewcommand{\ding}[2][1]{\scalebox{#1}{\oldding{#2}}}% Scale \oldding via optional argument
\begin{document}

\ding{196}\ \ding[1.1]{196}\ \ding[1.2]{196}\ \ding[1.5]{196}
\end{document}
```

`\ding[<factor>]{<element>}` now scales `\ding{<element>}` to `<factor>` as an added optional argument. Default is 1, implying no scaling.